# Where can I buy a mouse cable supporter?

Tags: mouse

Where to find mouse cable supporter as seen in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqerIwL0VIM#t=39s)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because literal shopping questions are clearly off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the term you are best searching for is 'Mouse Bungee'. Searching for that on amazon brings back these results

http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=mouse+bungee&tag=googhydr-21&index=aps&hvadid=4541355296&ref=pd_sl_npwnnz6up_e (UK amazon as I have no idea where you are from :D)

Comment: lol I have never seen such a thing, I fail to see the point?!

Comment: @danixd they stop the mouse cable slipping down the back of the desk and getting caught, etc, by providing a fixed (but flexible) distance of cable between your mouse and the bungee. I used to use one after winning it at a small LAN party and found it to be pretty handy, but my current desk configuration doesn't accomodate it (it's just too small) so I have the cable taped to the back of the desk for a similar effect...

Answer (score 0):

[3M Command Cable Hooks](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?client=safari&q=3m+command+cable&oe=UTF-8&cid=1219985620151634204&ei=Cud6TdnBFJSuigTFoYz9BQ&sa=title&ved=0CBEQ8wI#) work well